# Swashbuckle(5.0.0) with .Net Core 3 showing System.Reflection.Missing as default value for strings

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm porting a .net core 2.2 app to .net core 3.1 and have no idea of what's going on.
[image]

The generated swagger.json could also have other issues. We are using openapi-generator to generate the client files for our angular application and so far it isn't working.

Comment: Some code will be nice

Comment: Apparently adding [Optional] attribute to parameters causes this...